# Smoothness of the average value.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, smooth-functions

Let $\Omega$ be an open set in $\mathbb R^n$ and let $F : \Omega \times \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a smooth function. Let $G$ be the "average of $F$"
$$ G(x) = \int_0^1 F(x, t) dt.$$

By the intermediate value theorem, for each $x\in \Omega$, there is $t(x) \in [0,1]$ so that
$$ G(x) = F(x, t(x)).$$

> **Question**: Can I choose this $t$ smoothly?

Some observation: If $t$ is smooth and $F_t (x, t) \neq 0$ for all $(x, t)$, $t$ satisfies the PDE

$$ \nabla t = \frac{1}{F_t (x, t(x))} \big(\nabla G (x)- \nabla F(x, t(x))\big).$$

so when e.g. $n=1$, this becomes an ODE and is always solvable and $t$ is smooth. What happens for general $n$ and when $F_t$ is possibly zero somewhere? I believe that $t(x)$ can be chosen to be continuous, but how about smoothness?

Comment: For general $n\ge 1$, you can apply the implicit function theorem to the map $\Phi\colon \Omega\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$; with $\Phi(x,t)=F(x,t)-G(x)$. The condition to solve $\Phi(x,t(x))=0$ for smooth $t(x)$, locally around $(x_0,t_0)$ is then $0\neq \partial_t \Phi(x_0,t_0) = \partial_t F(x_0,t_0)$, just as in the $1$-dimensional case. Draw the submanifold $\{\Phi=0\}\subset \Omega \times \mathbb{R}$ to see that for general $\Phi$ problems may arise, even for continuity; I don't know whether the special structure of $\Phi$ allows to say more.